# Remove non-alphanumerical characters excluding space

Tags: c#, regex

I have this statement:

```
String cap = Regex.Replace(winCaption, @"[^\w\.@-]", "");
```

that transforms `"Hello | World!?"` to `"HelloWorld"`.

But I want to preserve space character, for example: `"Hello | World!?"` to `"Hello  World"`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is that one or two spaces between "Hello" and "World"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add a space to your set of characters, [^\w.@- ]

```
var winCaption = "Hello | World!?";
String cap = Regex.Replace(winCaption, @"[^\w\.@\- ]", "");
```

Note that you have to escape the 'dash' (-) character since it normally is used to denote a range of characters (for instance, [A-Za-z0-9])

Comment: I try, but I have this error:

parsing "[^\w\.- ]" - [x-y] range in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
string cap = Regex.Replace(winCaption, @"[^\w \.@-]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  String cap= Regex.Replace(winCaption, @"[^\w\.@\- ]", "");
```